# Razor pages identity profile image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, identity

I am learning razor pages and followed several decent examples on Microsoft to create a very rudimentary application. I was wondering if anyone had any resources on how I could add a profile image to razor pages. I am scaffolding identity in Visual studio but nowhere can I find any tutorial on how to integrate an image.

I do have a simple model and controller that will save a file path to the DB but fail to integrate this to the razor templates.

If anyone has any resources for what I am looking to learn I would greatly appreciate it. Apologies if this is very basic, I'm probably not using the correct terminology to search in Google.
identity user in the Db.

Comment: So do you have any model or controller or anything up to now? Where exactly the the bockings you are having with?

Comment: You can follow this https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/user-management-in-aspnet-core-mvc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help it helped me massively to resolve the issue. At the end of registering the image in the scaffolded razor pages Identity I had to use the code behind file register.cshtl.cs and add it to the Input module there and be consumed by the register.cshtml which now works perfectly.

I hope this helps someone else.

First I extended the ApplicationUser and added the migration.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

  
    public string? StreetAddress { get; set; }

    public string? City { get; set; }

 
    public string? PostalCode { get; set; }

    [ValidateNever]
    public string? ImageUrl { get; set; }  
    
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    [ValidateNever]
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Then added to the Input model in the Register.cshtml.cs

```
public class InputModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        //Added custom fields
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }


        public string? StreetAddress { get; set; }

        public string? City { get; set; }

        public string? PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [ValidateNever]
        public string? ImageUrl { get; set; }

        public string? Role { get; set; }

        public int? CompanyId { get; set; }

        [ValidateNever]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleList { get; set; }

        [ValidateNever]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CompanyList { get; set; }
    }`
```

Then in the on Post method add the file path to the database.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IFormFile file, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = CreateUser();

            string wwwRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            if (file != null)
            {
                string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var uploads = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath, @"images\companies");
                var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

                if (Input.ImageUrl != null)
                {
                    var oldImagePath = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath, Input.ImageUrl.TrimStart('\\'));
                }

                using (var fileStreams = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, fileName + extension), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(fileStreams);
                }
                Input.ImageUrl = @"\images\companies\" + fileName + extension;
            }
            else
            {
                Input.ImageUrl = @"\images\companies\QPQ-logo.jpg";
            }
            await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
            await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);

            user.Name = Input.Name;
            user.StreetAddress = Input.StreetAddress;
            user.City = Input.City;
            user.PostalCode = Input.PostalCode;
            user.PhoneNumber = Input.PhoneNumber;
            user.ImageUrl = Input.ImageUrl;

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                if (Input.Role == null)
                {
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, SD.Role_User_Indi);
                }
                else
                {
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, Input.Role);
                }
                var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                }
                else
                {
                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }`
```

One of the first mistakes I made was not declaring the front-end form as a multipart form in the Register.cshtml.

```
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1><div class="row pt-4">
<div class="col-md-8">
    <form id="registerForm" class="row" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h2>Create a new account.</h2>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

        <div class="form-floating py-2 col-12">
            <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" aria-required="true" />
            <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-floating py-2 col-6">
            <input asp-for="Input.Name" class="form-control" aria-required="true" />
            <label asp-for="Input.Name"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
       
        <div class="form-floating py-2 col-6">
            <input asp-for="Input.StreetAddress" class="form-control" />
            <label asp-for="Input.StreetAddress"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.StreetAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating py-2 col-6">
            <input asp-for="Input.City" class="form-control" />
            <label asp-for="Input.City"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.City" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating py-2 col-6">
            <input asp-for="Input.PostalCode" class="form-control" />
            <label asp-for="Input.PostalCode"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.PostalCode" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating py-2 col-6">
            <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" aria-required="true" />
            <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating py-2 col-6">
            <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" aria-required="true" />
            <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating py-2 col-6">
            <select asp-for="Input.Role" asp-items="@Model.Input.RoleList" class=form-select>
                <option disabled selected>-Select Role-</option>
            </select>

        </div>
        <div class="form-floating py-2 col-6">
            <select asp-for="Input.CompanyId" asp-items="@Model.Input.CompanyList" class=form-select>
                <option disabled selected>-Select Company-</option>
            </select>

        </div>
        <div class="form-floating py-2 col-12">
            <label asp-for="Input.ImageUrl"></label>
            <input asp-for="Input.ImageUrl" type="file" id="uploadBox" name="file" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <button id="registerSubmit" type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Register</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <section>
        <h3>Use another service to register.</h3>
        <hr />
        @{
            if ((Model.ExternalLogins?.Count ?? 0) == 0)
            {
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            There are no external authentication services configured. See this <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715">article
                            about setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services</a>.
                        </p>
                    </div>
            }
            else
            {
                    <form id="external-account" asp-page="./ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                @foreach (var provider in Model.ExternalLogins)
                            {
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.DisplayName</button>
                            }
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
            }
        }
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I do have a simple model and controller that will save a file path to
> the DB but fail to integrate this to the razor templates.

**Model:**

Let's assume you have Identity base Model as below:

```
public class IdentityUser
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

Now you would like to add `profile picture` functionality there:
So you could extent your class as below:

```
public class IdentityExtendedModel : IdentityUser
    {
       
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePictureLocation { get; set; }
    }
```

**Identity View Model:**

We don't want to manipulate our `identity Model` directly while submitting our form inputso I will use `viewModel`

```
public class IdentityViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [Phone]
        [Display(Name = "Phone number")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Profile Picture")]
        public byte[] ProfilePicture  { get; set; }
    }
```

**View Upload Profile Picture:**

```
@model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.IdentityViewModel


<form  asp-action="CreateIdentityProfilePic" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
                <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Username"></label>
                <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PhoneNumber"></label>
                <input asp-for="PhoneNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button id="update-profile-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProfilePicture" style="width: 100%;"></label>
                @if (Model.ProfilePicture != null)
                {
                    <img id="profilePicture" style="width:350px;height:350px; object-fit:cover" src="data:image/*;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ProfilePicture))">
                }
                else
                {
                    <img id="profilePicture" style="width:350px;height:350px; object-fit:cover" src="">
                }
                <input type="file"
                       accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.tif"
                       asp-for="ProfilePicture"
                       class="form-control"
                       style="border:0px!important;padding: 0px;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 30px;"
                       onchange="document.getElementById('profilePicture').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProfilePicture" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateIdentityProfilePic(InputModel model, IFormFile profilePicture)
        {
            if (profilePicture == null || profilePicture.Length == 0)
            {
                return Content("File not selected");
            }
            var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "ImageName/Cover", profilePicture.FileName);
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await profilePicture.CopyToAsync(stream);
                stream.Close();
            }



            if (model == null)
            {
                return Content("Invalid Submission!");
            }
            var identityModel = new IdentityModel
            {
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                Username = model.Username,
                PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber,
                ImageName = profilePicture.FileName,
                ProfilePictureLocation = path,
             
            };
            _context.Add(identityModel);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("IdentityProfilePicList");

        }
```

**Note:** When you would submit `Upload profile Picture view` this controller should receive the request.

**Controller Profile Picture List:**

```
public ActionResult IdentityProfilePicList()
        {
            var memberList = _context.identityModels.ToList();
            return View(memberList);
        }
```

**View Profile Picure List:**

```
@model IEnumerable<DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.IdentityExtendedModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}


<div class="form-row">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success">Create New</a>

            </td>
            <form method="get" action="#">

            <td style="padding-right:760px">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="btnNavbarSearch" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Username)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProfilePictureLocation)
            </th>
            <th>
                Member Details
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="~/ImageName/Cover/@item.ImageName"
                     class="rounded-square"
                     height="50" width="75"
                     style="border:1px"
                     asp-append-version="true" accept="image/*" />
                   
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="EditMember" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-memberId="@item.Id">Details</a> |  <a asp-action="EditMember" class="btn btn-warning" asp-route-memberId="@item.Id">Edit</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Database:**

[image]

**Note:** If you need any further assistance on this please check this [`GitHub repository`.](https://github.com/kironiitdu/Dotnet6App/blob/master/DotNet6MVCWebApp/Views/Animal/MemberList.cshtml)

Comment: Awe, thanks so much for taking the time to answer. I really appreciate it. :-) It's very well explained. I'll get started on this today and attempt to implement it.  Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, I think I implemented what you suggested but I have run into an issue with the id. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to get the IdentityUser Id to be used in my ApplicationUser Model and controller. Could you check this out? https://github.com/muccauleysulkin/QuidProQuo

Comment: It would be great if you could share the specific code where you are having blockings, its really hard to check your github repository and find the desired code.